# What is a Resource Server when it comes to Microservices?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, microservices

I am very confused about what is Resource Server in oAuth .

Is Resource Server something like API Gateway? or is Resource Server a business type of Microservice like for example "search microservice", "shopping cart microservice"?

If I have Authorization Server, API Gateway, and 15 business type Microservices behind the API gateway, does it mean I have 15 Resource Servers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resource server in [OAuth2 terminology](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.1) is the service where the client uses the access token to manipulate the user's data.

Whether you have 15 resource servers depend on who does the token validation. If you're API gateway is validating the access token before relaying the request, then you your API gateway would be the resource server. If every microservice validates its own token, then you would have 15 resource servers.

Comment: thank you for your reply. My API Gateway does validate the token but it is a very simple validation just too check if the token is valid and is not expired. Each downstream Microservice also performs token validation and extracts JWT claims, and creates security context, so that method-level security can be used for each endpoint this particular Microservice exposes. Can I assume that in this case each downstream Microservice is also a Resource Server?

Comment: Thank you, MvdD!

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: I have been trying to but I would not let me because I do not have enough reputation. I am a new user on Stackoverflow. But I will keep on checking it and will accept the answer as soon as it let me.

Comment: No worries, you should be able to accept the answer, but you do not have enough reputation to up-vote. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235